# Get HTML tag of a given element in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Let's say I have following HTML in my source code:

```
...
<span id=myElement>some text</span>
...
```

Let's also say that I have located this element via:

```
...
${web_element}  Get Webelement  id:myElement
...
```

Now I want to get the html tag of this located element, with something like:

```
...
${tag}  Some Keyword To Get the HTML of a located Element  ${web_element}
Log To Console  ${tag}  >> "span"
...
```

How would I get the HTML Tag of this element now in Robotframework? I could implement some Python code, but I can't believe, that there is no other, already bultin, feature, to get the tag of the element now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web elements have a `tag_name` attribute which you can access with robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

Example:

```
${web_element}  Get Webelement  id:myElement
log  The tag is ${web_element.tag_name}
```